# Establishing an Epsilon for most_common() in python

Tags: python, histogram, counter, frequency

I am trying to use the `most_common()` function from Python's [collections](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#module-collections) module and am wondering if there is a way to establish an epsilon (or a slight offset) so that in order for a number to be enumerated in the `most_common` array of tuples, it does not have to be exact.

For example, if I call `most_common` on this array:

```
(2.9, 3.0, 3.1, 4, 4, 5)
```

It will return:

```
((4, 2), (2.9, 1), (3.0, 1), (3.1, 1), (5, 1))
```

However, I am looking for a `most_common` function that would take into account an epsilon on, say `.1` and instead return:

```
((3, 3), (4, 2), (5, 1))
```

Comment: the thing here is that 2.9 and 3.1 are .2 apart, not .1. How would you expect your function to behave if you had 2.9, 3, 3.1, 3.2? is that one cluster, or 2?

Answer (score 0):

you can round the input data before calling `most_common`:

```
import numpy as np
from collections import Counter
d = [2.9, 3.0, 3.1, 4, 4, 5]
Counter(np.ma.round(d)).most_common()
```

which gives:

```
[(3.0, 3), (4.0, 2), (5.0, 1)]
```

Comment: thank you! This looks right to me, but I'm getting the error: TypeError: Not implemented for this type